# partial template specialization for friend classes?

Tags: c++, templates, partial, friend

I have a simple class X, and set of templatized classes Y<T,U>.  I'd like all classes Y where the first templatization parameter happens to be X to be a friend of X itself.  The following hopefully conveys what I want, but the friend statement gives a compile error.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Y {
};

class X {
    public:
        X(int value) : i(value) {}
        const int& getI()    const { return i; }
    private:
        int    i;
        template<class U> friend class Y<X,U>;
};
```

I'm not sure templatization of friend statements is allowed at all (let alone partial templatization of friend statements).  Is there a way to do this?  Or am I stuck listing out all the friends one-by-one?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: "a compile error" ... please add it to your question.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. [Friend declarations cannot refer to partial specializations, but can refer to full specializations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the non-partial part of your question, the syntax is:

```
class X {
    template<class T, class U> friend class Y;
};
```

I guess, in most cases that should be sufficient.

---

With C++11 you can actually friend a templated alias:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Y { };

class X {
    public:
        X(int value) : i(value) {}
        const int& getI()    const { return i; }
    private:
        int    i;
        template<class U> using YX = Y<X,U>;
        template<class U> friend class YX;
};
```

However, that does not seem to work (I'm not sure if the friend declaration above has any effect at all).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've opted for the non-partial approach you detailed.  Though it makes more friends than needed, all classes Y are behind-the-scenes for what I'm doing, and so shouldn't be a big problem.  Thanks for the syntax.  I too tried your non-partial approach.  Strangely it compiled, but didn't actually enable friendship as desired.  Not sure what it's doing.

Comment: @fk0 The first part should work. If not, what compiler/arguments are you using? The second part has no effect, as I did write.

Answer (score 14):

The [friend declaration page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) on cppreference.com specifies:

> Friend declarations cannot refer to partial specializations, but can refer to full specializations

So as chtz said you can have a non-partial specialization friend.

Edit:

See also another answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11046918/5776353