# A template friend class of a template class

Tags: c++, c++20

In the code below a template class `list` declared as a friend of a template class `link` to make `PrivateType` available in class `link`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class D>
class link
{
private:

    using PrivateType = int;

    template <class T1, class D1> friend class list;
};

template <class T, class D>
class list
{
private:

    using MyPrivateType = link<D>::PrivateType;

public:

    void add(MyPrivateType val)
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    list<int, int> l;
    l.add(5);
}
```

Is the friend class declared in a right way?

I also tried:

```
template <class T> friend list<T, D>;
```

but it does not compile.

**EDIT1:**

Doesn't the code declare redundant friends? For example, `list<std::string, std::vector>` becomes a friend of `link<int>` while I need `list<T, D>` be a friend of `link<D>` for any given `T` and `D` classes.

Comment: Compiles fine here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8rd874hjM

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, it compiles. It is a question about the coding style. Is `template <class T1, class D1> friend class list;` a good code?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What do you mean by *good code*?

Comment: @super yes, probably I asked a bit strange question, in this case, good code is a code that can't be made better.

Comment: @Dmitriano I believe you are looking for this (might be duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/44213761/10147399 TL;DR: no, you cannot have partial template specialization for friend classes.

Comment: @super, see EDIT1

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, it is it, I can't have `template <class T> friend list<T, D>`. And looks like nothing changed in C++20.