# Syntax for template friend declaration

Tags: c++, friend

I have `template <int N> class A;` and `template <typename T> class B;`.  How do I declare `B<A<N>>` to be a friend for all `N`?  `template <int N> friend B<A<N>>;` does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292795/how-to-declare-a-templated-struct-class-as-a-friend

Comment: @Mat That looks different, as OP only wants a subset of specializations of `B`.

Comment: A partial specialisation cannot be a friend.

Comment: Sorry for the intrusion. You said, "How do I declare `B<A<N>>` to be a friend for all `N`" - a friend to *what* exactly. `A<N>` ? The who-is-friending-who-and-where failure attempt in full-code would probably be a nice addition to this question, or at least make it clearer to people that don't necessarily sleep with the standard under their pillow.

Comment: @WhozCraig a friend to whatever class has a friend declaration I suppose. It doesn't really matter which class it is. You can try `class C { template <int N> friend B<A<N>>; };` (which doesn't work).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. yeah, the broken syntax (missing `class/struct`) was what was confusing me. I get it now. And I agree with your first comment.

Comment: @WhozCraig You can add `class/struct` and it still doesn't work, that's kinda the problem.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041274

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. As I said, I get it now; thus the reason for the "I agree with your first comment" conclusion.